# How to use XML::Simple when XML is in an object?

Tags: xml, perl, lwp

I have this code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use URI;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;

my $DBVersion = '';

my $url = URI->new('https://example.com');

$url->query_form(
    'sql' => 'select email,firstname from account for xml auto',
    'DBVersion' => $DBVersion
    );

my $response = LWP::UserAgent->new->get($url);
die "Error: ", $response->status_line unless $response->is_success;

print $response->content;
```

And now I would like to use `XML::Simple` on `$response->content`.

[From](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/04/18/perlxmlqstart1.html) can I see that they use

```
my $doc = $xs1->XMLin($file);

foreach my $key (keys (%{$doc->{species}})){
   print $doc->{species}->{$key}->{'common-name'} . ' (' . $key . ') ';
   print $doc->{species}->{$key}->{conservation}->final . "\n";
}
```

But my XML data in not in a file, but in an object created by the LWP module.

How can I parse that data with `XML::Simple`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XMLin()` can accept a string of XML as a parameter:

```
use XML::Simple;
my $ref = XMLin($response->content);
```

See [perldoc XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm#XMLin%28%29) for the details.